# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF) on line 230

Tags: themes, errors

Need you help, dont know what to do with it.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Home Page
 *
 * This is the template that displays all widgets included in homepage widget area.
 *
 * @package Mystery Themes
 * @subpackage News Portal Pro
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

get_header();

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/**
 * Home Top Section Area
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
if (is_active_sidebar('np_home_top_section_area')) {
    ?>
    <div class="np-home-top-section np-clearfix">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar('np_home_top_section_area'); ?>
    </div><!-- .np-home-top-section -->
    <?php
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/**
 * Home Middle Section Area
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

$top_title = get_field('top_news_title', 1620);
$top_posts = get_field('top_news_posts', 1620);
?>
    <div class="home_top_block">
        <div class="np-home-middle-section np-clearfix">
            <div class="left_section">
                <?php if (!empty($top_posts) && $top_title): ?>
                    <div class="np-home-top-section np-clearfix">
                        <h2 class="np-block-title">
                            <span class="np-title"><?= $top_title ?></span>
                        </h2>
                        <div class="top_block">
                            <?php foreach ($top_posts as $key => $post) { ?>
                                <div class="post_item">
                                    <div class="np-slide-thumb">
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                            <?= get_the_post_thumbnail($post) ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="description">
                                        <h3 class="post-title large-size"><a
                                                    href="<?= the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                        <div class="np-post-meta">
                                            <?php news_portal_posted_on(); ?>
                                            <?php news_portal_post_comment(); ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <? endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="middle-primary">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar('np_home_middle_section_area'); ?>
            </div>
        </div><!-- .np-home-middle-section -->
        <div class="middle-aside">
            <h2 class="np-block-title">
                <span class="np-title">Новини Вінниці</span>
            </h2>
            <?php
            $query = new WP_Query(
                array(
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => 40,
                    'category_name' => 'vinnytsia'
                )
            );
            $day = '';
            while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                if ($day != get_the_date()) {
                    echo "<div class='date_separator'><time>" . get_the_date('j F') . "</time></div>";
                    $day = get_the_date();
                }
                $post_class = '';
                $categories_list = array();
                foreach (get_the_category() as $categories) {
                    $categories_list[] = ' ' . $categories->slug;
                }
                foreach ($categories_list as $slug_class) {
                    $post_class .= $slug_class;
                }
            ?>
                <h4 class="pt-cv-title <?= $post_class ?>"><span class="entry-date"><time><?= the_time('G:i'); ?></time></span>
                    <a class="_self" href="<?= the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php echo the_title();
                        if (get_the_category()[0]->slug === 'video'): ?> <span class="video"></span> <?php endif; ?>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <a class="link_to_category" href="/archives/category/vinnytsia">Всі новини</a>
        </div><!-- .middle-aside -->
    </div>
<?php

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/**
 * Home middle fullwidth Section Area
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
if (is_active_sidebar('np_home_middle_fullwidth_area')) {
    ?>
    <div class="np-home-middle-fullwidth-section">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar('np_home_middle_fullwidth_area'); ?>
    </div><!-- .np-home-bottom-section -->
    <?php
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/**
 * Home middle fullwidth Section Area
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */


$video_title = get_field('video_block_title', 1620);
$video_posts = get_field('top_video', 1620);
?>
    <div class="middle-primary">
        <?php if (!empty($video_posts) && $video_title): ?>
            <div class="np-home-top-section np-clearfix">
                <h2 class="np-block-title">
                    <a href="<?= get_category_link(get_category_by_slug('video')->term_id); ?>"><?= $video_title; ?></a>
                </h2>
                <div class="video_block">
                    <div class="post_item top_item d-flex">
                        <div class="description">
                            <h3 class="post-title large-size">
                                <a href="<?= get_the_permalink($video_posts); ?>"><?= get_the_title($video_posts); ?></a>
                            </h3>
                            <div class="np-post-meta">
                                <?php
                                foreach ($video_posts as $key => $post) {
                                    news_portal_posted_on();
                                    news_portal_post_comment();
                                    break;
                                }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="np-slide-thumb">
                            <a href="<?= get_the_permalink($video_posts); ?>">
                                <?= get_the_post_thumbnail($video_posts) ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="video_list">
                        <?php
                        $args = array(
                            'numberposts' => 10,
                            'category' => get_category_by_slug('video')->term_id,
                            'orderby' => 'date',
                            'order' => 'DESC',
                            'post_type' => 'post',
                            'suppress_filters' => true
                        );
                        $video_news = get_posts($args);
                        foreach ($video_news as $key => $video) { ?>
                            <div class="video_item">
                                <div class="np-slide-thumb">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <?= get_the_post_thumbnail($video) ?>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <h6 class="post-title large-size">
                                    <a href="<?= get_permalink($video); ?>"><?= get_the_title($video); ?></a>
                                </h6>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <? endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/**
 * Home Bottom Section Area
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
if (is_active_sidebar('np_home_bottom_section_area')) {
    ?>
    <div class="np-home-bottom-section np-clearfix">
        <div class="bottom-primary">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar('np_home_bottom_section_area'); ?>
        </div><!-- .bottom-primary -->
        <div class="bottom-aside">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar('np_home_bottom_aside_area'); ?>
        </div><!-- .bottom-aside -->
    </div><!-- .np-home-bottom-section -->
    <?php
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/**
 * Home Bottom fullwidth Section Area
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
if (is_active_sidebar('np_home_bottom_fullwidth_area')) {
    ?>
    <div class="np-home-bottom-fullwidth-section">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar('np_home_bottom_fullwidth_area'); ?>
    </div><!-- .np-home-bottom-section -->
    <?php
}

get_footer();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
<? endif; ?>
```

on line 192. Change that to

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: unfortunately did not help

Comment: thanks a lot!!!  found another place where change.